# trying to add user input to api using axios in vue js but having an error?

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vuex

//this is my signupform.js where i have an object which have my form keys

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
import store from '../../store';
export default {
  name: 'Signupform',
  components: {
    Datepicker,store
  },
  data() {
    return {
      enter_details:
        {
          username: '',
          email: '',
          contactNumber: '',
          firstName: '',
          lastName:'',
          dob: '',
          password: '',
          repeat_password: ''
        }


    }
  },
  methods:{
    addtoAPI() {

      this.$store.dispatch('addtoapi',this.enter_details)
    }
  }
};
```

//this is my store's action

```
import vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios'
vue.use(vuex);

const store = new vuex.Store({
  actions: {

    addtoapi: ({commit}, enter_details) => {

      let newuser = {
        username: enter_details.username,
        email: enter_details.email,
        contactNumber: enter_details.contactNumber,
        firstName: enter_details.firstName,
        lastName: enter_details.lastName,
        dob: enter_details.dob,
        password: enter_details.password,
        repeat_password: enter_details.repeat_password,
      }
      console.log(newuser);
      axios.post('https://dev-api.mysc.io/int/api/v1', newuser)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  }
});
```

//now i am getting an error i.e

```
Signupform.js?22e4:28 Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.dispatch is not a function
    at VueComponent.addtoAPI (Signupform.js?22e4:28)
    at boundFn (vue.esm.js?efeb:190)
    at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2004)
    at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask
```

i am also getting one more error that when i try to see my store on vue on my browser it shows that "no vuex store"

please help me to resolve this error because i have alreaady

//this is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */


export const bus = new Vue();


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your store.js write this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
     //
});
```

instead of

```
export default({
     //
});
```

**UPD**: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/1t6mj52o/)

And you don't need to include store as a component:

```
// signupform.js file ...
components: {
    Datepicker,
    store // <--- this is unnessesary
},
```

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    theAction() {
      alert('Action fired');
    },
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  methods: {
    fireAction() {
      this.$store.dispatch('theAction')
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="fireAction">Press me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Vuex is not defined
    at eval (actions.js?44d5:6)
    at Object../src/store/actions.js (app.js:2303)

Comment: change it to `new vuex.Store({...})`. You got this error because you import vuex as `vuex` not `Vuex` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: i used this "export default new vuex.Store({" still i am getting error Signupform.js?22e4:28 Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.dispatch is not a function
    at VueComponent.addtoAPI (Signupform.js?22e4:28)

Comment: Can you add the whole code for your store? And what does `this.$store` object contain? I will add a small demo to my answer, maybe it'll point you to the right direction.

Comment: actually its an action so ia m writing this code in actions.js  of my store and as you said i have given the whole code of my actions.js above

Comment: for your store not only actions.js

Comment: Take a look at the example I provided with my answer. You don't init the store correct. You still didn't answer the question about the content `this.$store`. Please, consider everything I've written once again  and if it doesn't help provide more information if you want to get the right answer

Comment: i am still getting the same error, and her this.store.dispatch is basically  a call to the action and this.store refers to the store involved

Comment: I don't follow. I can't help you if you don't provide any informations I ask you to nor describing what exactly you have tried. Have you fixed your store initialisation (like I shown you in my demo)? What does `console.log(this.$store)` outputs?

Comment: you still need to export store module. why have you deleted `export default` statement?

Comment: output of console.log(this.$store)                                                 
{state: {…}, actions: undefined, getters: {…}, mutations: {…}, modules: {…}}
actions
:
undefined
getters
:
{}
modules
:
{}
mutations
:
{}
state
:
{}
__proto__
:
Object